# What does "world'll be shut of you" mean?

Tags: meaning

In *Sling Blade (1996)*, Karl visits his father after a long time:

> Karl: I studied on killing you. I studied about it quite a bit.
> But I reckon there's no need for it if all you're gonna do...
> is sit there in that chair. You'll be dead soon enough.
> And the **world'll be shut of you**.

What does "world'll be shut of you" mean? Closest phrase I know is "[Shut someone out](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/shut+someone+out)".
This one here is different.

Comment: Possibly a mis-spelling or phonetic spelling of "shot of you"?

Comment: It's not actually a "mis-spelling" - people deliberately enunciate both ***shot*** AND ***shut*** for this idiomatic usage. But [British English](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=to+be+shot+of+it%2Cto+be+shut+of+it&year_start=1919&year_end=2019&corpus=29&smoothing=10&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cto%20be%20shot%20of%20it%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cto%20be%20shut%20of%20it%3B%2Cc0) massively favours ***shot***, and it's primarily a BrE usage anyway (though when Americans *do* use it, they're just as likely to go with ***shut*** as with ***shot***).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

'to be or get **shut** of someone or something' is a variant of 'to be or get **shot** of someone or something'. It means to be rid of the person or thing.

*I was glad to be shut of my old car. It was always in the garage.*

> get shut of in British English
> or get shot of
> slang
>
> to get rid of

[Get shut of (Collins Dictionary)](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/get-shut-of)